# List all Processor topologies in a given Kafka Cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am new to Kafka Streams.
I would like to connect to Kafka Cluster and read all Stream Topologies.
Is there an API that would allow doing that?
I am looking at the `Topology` class, is there a way to list all Topologies? 
https://docs.confluent.io/5.5.0/streams/javadocs/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible. Brokers don't know anything about Kafka Streams applications.

Comment: Can one infer topology of a stream based on the internal topics? I read that they follow certain naming conventions

Comment: Well, your question was about `Topologies` internal topics won't help you to figure out the topology. All Kafka Streams applications register a consumer group though, so you can see what apps are running (even if plain Consumer and Kafka Streams app would look the same). Also, not all Kafka Streams app use internal topics to it won't be 100% relieable.